# List directories that are no target of a symlink

Tags: bash, directory

Using Bash shell.

I have a directory with a large number of subdirectories.

Symbolic links points to some them. This makes managing the content quite convenient because the symlinks have more expressive names than the directory names.

For some other directories, this redirection job is still incomplete.

Is there a Bash way to list the directories that are **no target of a symlink** (contained in the same parent folder, if this simplifies the matter)?
To me this would return the directories that I have still to work on and spare some error-prone donkey work.

Comment: As a starting point, you need to know that a target file or directory does not have the list of its links. The filesystem contains the **link-to** information, but not the **link-from**. So you will have to recreate this missing information by collecting all the **link-to** `(1,1)` cardinality relation, by populating a new `(1,n)` cardinality relation table of `(destination-path, source-path)`

Comment: Broadly speaking, symlink is just a path to the target and target knows nothing about symlinks. If you know the locations of the targets/links then something like `join -v1 <(ls LOCATIONTARGETS | sort) <(ls LOCATIONLINKS | xargs readlink | sort)` should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Solution requires GNU CoreUtils:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

{
  # Create a list of null delimited symbolic links destination
  find . -type l -printf ./%l\\0

  # Append directories to the null delimited list
  find . -type d -print0
} |

# Sort the null delimited list
sort -z |

# Extract unique entries (those having no symbolic link)
uniq -zu |

# Produce a human-readable list by replacing null delimiters by newlines
xargs -0l
```

Comment: Why null termination is needed? Is this solution handling case of multiline filenames?

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, it handles names with newlines or other non-printable characters. Since it already uses the CoreUtils `find` command with its `-printf` argument, it assumes the other null enabled CoreUtils commands are available and use it.

Comment: This will additionally print the targets of the symbolic links in current directory pointing outside this directory. Also will exclude only links that have been created relatively exactly from this current directory. For the rest of cases will print both the directory and the non-relative-to-here target.

Comment: @thanasisp I know these limitations, but thank you for pointing this out. I wrote an earlier solution using an intermediary step of `xargs -0 realpath -z --relative-to=. | sed -z 's_^_./_'` that would fix non-relative links as relative destination. I thought the added complexity exceeded poster's seemingly simple context, while still only handling one edge case with non-relative symlinks but not links to a different branch.